# Incomplete and random numbers of Friends list using asmack

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack

I am getting random numbers of friends from the asmack roster in android.

i am using

```
        roster = connection.getRoster();
        Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
        return roster.getEntries();
```

please help...

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same method to retrive roster entries and I am getting perfectly. Kindly check with your code once. Comment here if you need any help.

```
ArrayList<RosterEntry> rosterEntriesc;
    try{
                connection = MyXMPPConnection.getXMPPConnection();
                roster = connection.getRoster(); 
                rosterEntriesc = new ArrayList<RosterEntry>(roster.getEntries());
       }
catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Ya thats what i am saying it is true that this is the method but i am still getting random numbers of roster entries

Comment: what you mean by random numbers of roster entries?

Comment: Some times i get 1 or 2 friends sometimes all and some time none